# Image sticks out of border

Tags: html, css

The image goes out of a white border and I want it to be inside:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/AQI5SzX.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.whitebox {
  position: relative;
  left: -5%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

div.titleclass {
  position: relative;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #bdb76b6b;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/vah2G4d.jpeg");
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: rotate(7deg) translate(-2.3%, -20%);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 105%;
}

div.title {
  font-family: "Rockwell";
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-align: left;
  color: #006400;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="whitebox">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="titleclass">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="title">MODULO ISCRIZIONE SOFTAIR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="Modulo_softair_rework.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? Is it that there's any amount of white under the "Modulo" text? Or is it that the top right and bottom left corners show an angled white section? Or something else?

Comment: No think It like this. You have a White Square and you drop on top of It a black Square. You only want the party where the black Square contacts the White Square. So remove the party that do not touch the White box. That's what i want. The ritardo image sticker out of the White box and overlaps the background

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow:hidden to parent div which has the border radius.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/AQI5SzX.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.whitebox {
  position: relative;
  left: -5%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3%;
  /*here is the change */
  /*here is the change */
  /*here is the change */
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.titleclass {
  position: relative;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #bdb76b6b;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/vah2G4d.jpeg");
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: rotate(7deg) translate(-2.3%, -20%);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 105%;
}

div.title {
  font-family: "Rockwell";
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-align: left;
  color: #006400;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="whitebox">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="titleclass">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="title">MODULO ISCRIZIONE SOFTAIR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="Modulo_softair_rework.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of height:75% and use top to reposition

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/AQI5SzX.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.whitebox {
  position: relative;
  left: -5%;
  top:-25%;
  width: 75%;
  
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

div.titleclass {
  position: relative;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #bdb76b6b;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/vah2G4d.jpeg");
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: rotate(7deg) translate(-2.3%, -20%);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 105%;
}

div.title {
  font-family: "Rockwell";
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-align: left;
  color: #006400;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="whitebox">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="titleclass">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="title">MODULO ISCRIZIONE SOFTAIR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="Modulo_softair_rework.js"></script>
```